# Make BLoC state persistent for making an offline app with flutter

Tags: flutter, state, offline

I want to create a flutter application that saves the states so that my application can work offline. 
I use the BLoC pattern with flutter_bloc to manadge my states.
I would also like to make sure that when my application becomes online the changes made are synchronized with the server that hosts the database

Answer (score 0):

U can use Hydrated to persist urs streams:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/hydrated

Second choise is use a Sqlite:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/moor_flutter

I choose "moor" lib cuz make my Sqlite reactive.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem of how to send updates once the client comes back online